"Until" with tenses simple and continuous
Can you tell me how to use "until" with tenses?
1 I did my homework before/until she arrived
2 I was doing my homework before/until she arrived
I think that if we use "before" 1 shows that homework was completed and 2 that it was just ongoing. On the other hand with "until" both sentences show that doing homework was ogoing untill her arrival. If I am right what's the difference between using simple or continuous tenses with "until"?

It depends on the surrounding sentences. If you were discussing what happened while doing your homework, continuous would be more appropriate.

As you say, I did my homework would normally be understood to mean I completed it. But it doesn't make sense to say that you completed an action until a certain time, because it isn't an ongoing activity. Therefore did in that context must mean was doing.

@Kate Bunting do you think that it is correct to use "I did" not "I was doing" with "until"? Even , my friend wears a T-shirt with a sign on it "I ran until I saw her". So it must be correct?

I didn't say that it was incorrect to say I did [something] until [a certain time]. I said that, before until, did would always be understood as an ongoing action and not a completed one. You asked why that is so, and I attempted to explain.

Thank you very much

All four variations are possible and valid, and have different implications.
This example hinges on the ambiguity, discussed at a lot of length elsewhere, between whether "did my homework" means "did some of it" or "did all of it." (There are other conversations on this site about "I read a book," which is even more flexible since it's something that's often completed in multiple sittings.)
Since "until" has a meaning about interruption, it can change the meaning of the verb phrase. This works with lots of verbs. I can think of many examples in which simple past would imply completion: "I ran a marathon yesterday." With no other explanation, this probably means I ran the whole race. "I ran a marathon yesterday until I pulled a muscle." This seems to mean that I abandoned the race when I got injured. I could make similar examples out of "I painted my house [until it rained]," "I chopped wood [until the axe broke]," etc. Changing any of these to past progressive doesn't really affect the action of "until."
The "before" examples are inherently a bit vague. How long before? How much homework? It doesn't say. For these, the verb tense matters more. The simple past keeps that implication that the task was probably finished, within reason. ("I did my homework before she arrived"? Probably means finished it. "I read a book before she arrived"? Maybe finished it, maybe just read some. "I painted the ceiling of the Sistine Chapel before she arrived"? Probably means just did some work on it. See my longest rant to date about the importance of context.) But the progressive tense focuses on the state of activity, so it's talking more about "the doing" than the task as a whole. "I was reading" doesn't really make any claims about finishing. Come to think of it, this is true whether or not we add any clauses about anyone "arriving." "I did my homework": probably means finished. "I was doing my homework": probably does not mean finished.
